# Trying to make a hangman program, can't get it to show guessed letters

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a hangman program. The phrase they have to guess is "bad hair day", and they see "*** *** **". When the user inputs a character nothing changes. I'm not 100% sure were I am going wrong but maybe it's in the passwordlabel2 or somewhere in the loop.

Demo Class

```
 public class SecretPhrase {
    int wrong = 0; //ignore for now
    String phrase = "Bad hair day"; //hidden, what the user has to guess
    String hiddenPhrase = "*** **** ***"; //what the user originally sees

    public void changeLetter(char input)
    {
          StringBuilder checker = new StringBuilder(input);
         StringBuilder(hiddenPhrase);
         boolean wrongGuess = true;
         for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++)
         {
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == input){
                checker.setCharAt(i, input);
                wrongGuess = false;
            }
         }
         hiddenPhrase = checker.toString();
         if (wrongGuess){
             wrong++;


    }



    }

    private void StringBuilder(String hiddenPhrase) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

---

UI Class

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class SecretPhraseUI extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    SecretPhrase phrase = new SecretPhrase();
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Enter a letter to guess the phrase."  ); //sets label to display message
    JLabel passwordLabel2 = new JLabel( phrase.hiddenPhrase  ); //sets label to display message
    JTextField inputBox = new JTextField(40); //sets text field
    JButton runButton = new JButton("Run"); //button that starts program
    Container con = getContentPane(); //gets container


    public void init()
    {
        con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//sets flowlayout
        con.add(new JLabel());      //jlabel container
        con.add(inputBox);  //input box container
        con.add(runButton);  //run button container
        con.add(passwordLabel); //password label container
        con.add(passwordLabel2); //password label container
        runButton.addActionListener(this);//looks to see if run is clicked
        inputBox.addActionListener(this);//looks to see if input box is used
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String userInput = inputBox.getText(); //gets input from user





    }
    }
```

Comment: There is nowhere where you try to update the `passwordLabel2` label. You aren't even calling `changeLetter()`

Comment: everytime I try to call changeLetter I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make label.setText("The text you want to be displayed after action") . So when you do check the char, then do passwordLabel2.setText(phrase.hiddenPhrase) if the char is guessed right. :)

Working example

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SecretPhraseUI 
    extends JApplet
    implements ActionListener {

    SecretPhrase phrase = new SecretPhrase();
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Enter a letter to guess the phrase."); //sets label to display message
    JLabel passwordLabel2 = new JLabel(
            phrase.hiddenPhrase  ); //sets label to display message
    JTextField inputBox = new JTextField(40); //sets text field
    JButton runButton = new JButton("Run"); //button that starts program
    Container con = getContentPane(); //gets container

    public void init() {
        con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//sets flowlayout
        con.add(new JLabel());      //jlabel container
        con.add(inputBox);  //input box container
        con.add(runButton);  //run button container
        con.add(passwordLabel); //password label container
        con.add(passwordLabel2); //password label container
        runButton.addActionListener(this);//looks to see if run is clicked
        inputBox.addActionListener(this);//looks to see if input box is used
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!inputBox.getText().isEmpty()) {
            phrase.changeLetter(
                    inputBox.getText().charAt(0)); //gets input from user 
            passwordLabel2.setText(phrase.hiddenPhrase);
        }
    }
}


public class SecretPhrase {
    int wrong = 0; //ignore for now
    String phrase = "Bad hair day"; //hidden, what the user has to guess
    String hiddenPhrase = "*** **** ***"; //what the user originally sees

    public void changeLetter(char input) {
         StringBuilder checker = new StringBuilder(hiddenPhrase);
         boolean wrongGuess = true;
         for (int i=0; i<phrase.length(); i++) {
            if (phrase.charAt(i) == input){
                checker.setCharAt(i, input);
                wrongGuess = false;
            }
         }
         hiddenPhrase = checker.toString();
         if (wrongGuess){
             wrong++;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One thing I'm really confused about. When I made the stringbuilder it gave me an error and it wouldn't go away unless I put the void stringbuilder method. How come you didn't need it to get it working?

Comment: "StringBuilder(hiddenPhrase);" line was recognized as a call to method StringBuilder of this.

Your programm doesn't need this method 
   private void StringBuilder(String hiddenPhrase) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

so the call StringBuilder(hiddenPhrase) is also not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you've done anything with the user input. You could do something with the user input. Append the user input to another String and use the setText method of a label to update a label with the user input.